# Why does Sookie not get high from vampire blood?

Tags: true-blood

Through out the series Sookie Stackhouse receives blood from Bill Compton many times, however she never seems to get high from the vampire blood as other characters do when they take "V".

Is this because "V" is usually taken differently, rather than sucking from directly from a vampire as Sookie does?

NB: I'm only up to season 2 of *True Blood* please use spoiler tags if your answer involves spoilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently this:](http://charlaineharris.com/?page_id=69)

> Q. What’s the deal with the blood bond? Why do some people go crazy
>   when they drink the blood of drained vampires? **Why doesn’t Sookie get**
>   **high when she takes blood from Bill or Eric?**
>
> A. Here goes: everything’s variable when it comes to vampire blood
>   being ingested by humans. There is no formula that says, for example,
>   that 2 ounces of vamp blood will make every blood junkie go nuts.
>   Vampire blood is like any other street drug in that respect. The
>   variables include the age of the blood (how long it’s been out of the
>   vampire), the age of the vampire, and the mental condition and
>   previous drug use of the imbiber. Blood taken straight from the
>   vampire does not necessarily make the drinker high, unless he or she
>   is already an addict. A blood bond may be formed when a vampire and a
>   human exchange blood, though often it takes more than once. It also
>   may depend on the emotional bond existing between them.

***Then you have this side of the argument. But beware this is just fans being fans.***

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090904190020AAs4lkM

[This wikia article is a little TMI, so beware.](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_Blood)

> If vampire blood is consumed by a human (or any other creature) in small dose (one or two drops), it will heighten the senses, increase strength, make an intense sexual experience, and cause hallucinations. **The effects are different with each person;** however, if the blood is taken in a large dose, it causes several different effects, such as healing someone who has injuries, even if they are dangerously close to death, and metaphysically or spiritually bond the drinker with the vampire in question. If taken in a large dose when there is no injury on the human, they will have an extremely increased libido.

Comment: tl;dr: because it would short-circuit the entire show if Sookie got high every time she drank a vampire's blood.

Comment: @JMD I am not a sookie expert, so I can't examine the tv trope unless I have evidence.